# can't get stream_set_timeout to work in foreach array loop

Tags: php, timeout, fsockopen

I'm not so familiar with PHP but have been able to get a script running that will check if a certain port is open for a number of local network computers.
the downside is that some pc's are offline and I can't get the timeout of the *fsockopen* function lower then 1 second (0.001 second would be enough)

I've found the *stream_set_timeout* function but can't seem to get it to work.
I'm pretty sure it's just in the wrong place, and hope someone can point out where it should go.

now I get this error:

> Warning: stream_set_timeout() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given

snippet:

```
$timeout = 1000;
foreach ($farm as $pc){
$check = @fsockopen($pc, $port);
stream_set_timeout($check,0,$timeout);


if (is_resource($check))

{
   echo $pc . " online";       
   fclose($check);
}
else
{
   echo $pc . " offline";
}

}
```

---

current solution:

```
foreach ($farm as $pc){
$check = @fsockopen($pc,$port,$errCode,$errStr,0.001);



if (is_resource($check))

{
   echo $pc . " online";       
   fclose($check);
}
else
{
   echo $pc . " offline";
}

}
```

Comment: If parameter 1 is a boolean that means fsockopen() failed, as it returns a resource on success and false on failure.

Comment: stream_set_timeout() should be inside the if statement where you check that $check is a resource.

Comment: thanks!

noticed by now I can also use a " 0.001 " value with the regular fsockopen timeout...